# difference between Sign-propagating right shift and Zero-fill right shift in javascript?

Tags: javascript

As i know,

**Sign-propagating right shift (a >> b) :** Shifts a in binary representation b bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off.

Ex: 8>>2 will return 2.because binary 1000 will shift 2 times right and return 0010.

**Zero-fill right shift (a >>> b):** Shifts a in binary representation b bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off, and shifting in zeros from the left.

Ex: 8>>2 return 2.it also retun the same.

then what is difference between `>>` and `>>>` operator and why javascript has these two operator instead of one or if i am wrong then please guide me to get right concept?

Comment: Try `-8 >> 2`: -2  vs.  `-8 >>> 2`:  1073741822

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift can give you the correct answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bitwise operators assume their operands are 32-bit signed integers.

`00000000000000000000000000001000` in base 2 equals `8` in base 10.

---

In `8 >> 2`, the sign-propagating shift-right operator (>>) shifts the binary number two places, preserving the sign (which is the first bit):

`00000000000000000000000000000010` in base 2 equals `2` in base 10.

In `8 >>> 2`, the zero-fill right-shift operator (>>>) shifts the binary number two places, filling in the left bits with 0s:

`00000000000000000000000000000010` in base 2 equals `2` in base 10

These are identical, simply because the first bit for positive binary numbers is a zero.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift)**:

> For non-negative numbers, zero-fill right shift and sign-propagating
>   right shift yield the same result.

---

For negative numbers, however, things look different:

`11111111111111111111111111111000` in base 2 equals `-8` in base 10.

In `-8 >> 2`, the sign-propagating shift-right operator (>>) shifts the binary number two places, preserving the sign:

`11111111111111111111111111111110` in base 2 equals `-2` in base 10.

In `-8 >>> 2`, the zero-fill right-shift operator (>>>) shifts the binary number two places, filling in the left bits with 0s:

`00111111111111111111111111111110` in base 2 equals `1073741822` in base 10.

Comment: can you give an example where each one is used in negative numbers and why would one use >> instead of >>> and vise-versa ?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this happens? `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is `9007199254740991` and `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(2)` is `"11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"` so then `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER >> 1` is `-1`.